# How to navigate to different page displaying the same tab item as selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have `TabControlView.xaml` as UserControl with two tabs `tab1` and `tab2`. I have Page1.xaml which uses `TabControlView.xaml`.

In content of `tab1` there are item which onclick the will display `Page2.xaml`. I am using same `TabControlView.xaml` in `Page2.xaml` as well, But `tab1` and `tab2` contents are empty.

What I want to achieve is even though I navigate to `Page2.xaml` and

When User click on `tab1` while displaying `Page2.xaml` I want to display `Page1.xaml` with active tab as `tab1`

When User click on `tab2` while displaying `Page2.xaml` I want to display `Page1.xaml` with active tab as `tab`

How can I achieve this. I am following MVVM framewrok.

How do we generally achieve this kind of features? . For example Microsoft Store has this feature

Comment: Stuff like selection tracking in MVVM is done via a CollectionView. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx It allows Sorting, Grouping, Filtering and Selection Tracking. A instance is implicitly created from any collection you hand the UI clases. But in many cases it becomes nesssesary to create it yourself, so you get control over it's behavior/how and when it is shared. Also in MVVM user controls are somewhat rare. Usually Type Targetting Data Templates offer the same advantages, without any of hte downsides.

Comment: If you want the exact same models and features in both the xamls then create a single viemodel for both of them